# Tutorial to port XNA game to MonoGame on iOS?

Tags: xna, ios, iphone, monogame

Are there any good tutorials to convert a current XNA game to work iOS using MonoGame?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Probably not; I would recommend starting with just porting to MonoGame to make it work, then translate concepts like touch into an iOS realm.

Comment: Make A Monogame IOS project, and copy your code in. Put all of your .xnb files into the Content folder, and set the properties of each .xnb file on 'build' to Content and 'Copy' to copy if newer.

Comment: @Potato Post that as an answer because even though its a very simple answer it is the correct one and should be accepted.

Comment: I have now rewritten my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are any specifically about porting to iOS yet but there are a few good tutorials around that might help. Check out this discussion on the forums lists current tutorials.
https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/439595

There's also another related thread about ideas for new tutorials.
https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/439728

I'm currently only using MonoGame to make games for Windows and port them to Android. I suspect the process is fairly similar though, and it's not too difficult. Give it a go and see if you run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

Download Monogame And Mono, Along With Xamarin Studio.

Now Create A New Monogame iOS project. (You may get an error because i believe you can only make iOS projects on a Mac machine)

Now Copy All Of Your Code Files In.

Now For The Final Part, Put All Of The Built .XNB files from your projects Content Folder into your iOS's Content Folder As A Link To The Original XNB.
(these should be located at ProjectName\ProjectName\ProjectName\bin\x86\Debug\Content)

From here, foreach of your .XNB files set there build action to 'Content' And Copy to 'Copy If Newer'. Now Test It And It Should Work. (this should work, for i have only tested this on android and not on iOS, but it should be the same process).